Movie featuring a doctor who was traumatized as a child
I know I saw this movie in the 90's.  American movie, I want to say it was a comedy but I'm not positive.
All I have is one specific scene.  Not enough to Google on, but if you've seen the movie you'll definitely remember this.
In the movie, there was a scene with a doctor who needed to perform some emergency operation.  While he's sweating it out, he has a flashback of growing up.  His dad was a doctor, and at some party he has his son perform some mock operation.  However, when the kid cuts into whatever it was he was operating on, a bunch of confetti or something flew out of it and it scared the bejesus out of him.
Anyone recall this movie?

Sounds like the silly Young Doctors in Love from 1982 starring Sean Young, Michael McKean, Dabney Coleman and a few billion other known faces. From IMDb:

An 'Airplane'-style spoof of hospital soap operas: a brilliant young trainee can't stand the sight of blood; a doctor romances the head nurse in order to get the key to the drugs cabinet; there's a mafioso on the loose disguised as a woman - in other words all the usual ingredients present and correct, though in this case the laughs are intentional.

In one scene:

The interns watch as Simon begins his surgical test, but the pressure causes him to recall a traumatic experience from childhood, in which his parents played a practical joke on him during a mock “surgery” on a pinata. Overwhelmed by the pressure, Simon runs out of the room and retreats to a nearby cemetery to contemplate his future.

Here's the trailer:




Walt to the rescue again!  Thanks!

I love that at 1:16 in the trailer, you can see the boom mic at the top of the screen.  :oD  That'll tell ya a little something about the movie.

Though to be fair, that's probably because it's a TV transfer
